# Отправка сообщения по нажатию

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

VK Bot на Python, я написал код для клавиатуры, и у меня не получается сделать так чтобы новое сообщение отправилось после нажатия кнопки (оно ниже).

```py
if text == "start":
    keyboard = VkKeyboard()
    button = ["....", "...."]
    button_colors = [VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY, VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE]

    for btn, btn_color in zip(button, button_colors):
        keyboard.add_button(btn, btn_color)

    send_message(user_id, "Text", keyboard)

    send_message(user_id, "Text 2")
    # мне нужно что бы вот это отправилось после нажатия
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='123')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, .group_id)

button = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
button.add_button('Кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
vk.messages.send(user_id=event.obj.from_id, random_id=get_random_id(),
                         keyboard=button.get_keyboard(),
                         message='Текс с которым отправится кнопка')

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.obj.text == 'Кнопка':
        vk.messages.send(user_id=event.obj.from_id, random_id=get_random_id(),
                         message='Вы нажали на кнопку "Кнопка"')
```

необходимо отловить событие нажатия, [vk_longpoll](https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll)

- [callback_bot](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/callback_bot.py)
- [longpoll](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/longpoll.py)